# Can you program Atmega32M1 with UART?

Tags: spi, uart, atmega

I have been reading datasheet over datasheet and seems to find nothing about this. I know I can use SPI_A for both bootloading and programming the atmega32m1. But can I use UART? And should I go with atmega32m1 at all or just replace it with other micro-controller. I am using this to design an ESC and form factor is important.

Comment: You have a choice of debugWire or ISP. If you want uart, then you'll need to write a bootloader similar to what Arduino does.
As for the decision of if you should use the mega32m1 - that's up to you. We don't know your requirements or constraints. There's probably a choice of a zillion devices that might suit your needs. It probably comes down to what you have experience with, what tools you have and/or are free, is there much support for it and can you purchase it easily.

Comment: What is an ESC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but...

What I mean by that is you must first program the 32M1 with your initial program using the Microchip-provided debugWIRE interface.  For that you will need a programmer that supports the debugWIRE protocol.  Something like the AtmelICE or one of a number of 3rd party ISP (in circuit programmer) suppliers.

To program via the UART, you will need to write and program, as above, an application that will accept your data over the UART and "self-program" the new data.  Generally this means a "boot loader" and you can find examples of this in my places including the 32M1 Complete Datasheet.

This is basically how the Arduino, and for that matter nearly all other microcontrollers that are common in the market today.  The MCU in the Arduino is first programmed using the built-in programming interface and then a serial-programming protocol is available.